# Android: Is it possible to have different handlers for drawableLeft and the text inside a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I was wondering if it is possible to have different behavior depending on a click on the icon and the text inside a `TextView`... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks... So in that case, I will have to resort to a textview and an imageview :(